# Tinkerpop Gremlin server MissingPropertyException for SparkGraphComputer in remote mode

Tags: groovy, titan, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

I am new to tinkerpop, gremlin and groovy.
I have configured a Tinkerpop Gremlin Server and Console [v3.2.3] with verified integration with HDFS and Spark.

Next I try to execute below code using gremlin console in local mode, everything works fine, a spark job is submitted and successfully processed.

```
:load data/grateful-dead-janusgraph-schema.groovy
graph = JanusGraphFactory.open('conf/connection.properties')
defineGratefulDeadSchema(graph)
graph.close()

hdfs.copyFromLocal('data/grateful-dead.kryo','data/grateful-dead.kryo')

graph = GraphFactory.open('conf/hadoop-graph/hadoop-load.properties')
blvp = BulkLoaderVertexProgram.build().writeGraph('conf/connection.properties').create(graph)
graph.compute(SparkGraphComputer).program(blvp).submit().get()
```

Next I connect gremlin console to gremlin server as remote using below command.

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
```

After this I execute above code prefixing statements with ":> ". As soon as I submit last line which is submitting processing to SparkGraphComputer, I get below exception at the server -

```
[WARN] AbstractEvalOpProcessor - Exception processing a script on request [RequestMessage{, requestId=097785d6-7114-44fb-acbc-1b116dfdaac2, op='eval', processor='', args={gremlin=graph.compute(SparkGraphComputer).program(blvp).submit().get(), bindings={}, batchSize=64}}].
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: SparkGraphComputer for class: Script4
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:307)
        at Script4.run(Script4.groovy:1)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:619)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:448)
        at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:233)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.ScriptEngines.eval(ScriptEngines.java:119)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.lambda$eval$2(GremlinExecutor.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am unable to understand what does MissingPropertyException means in groovy, is it similar to NoClassDefFound in java?

I believe some configuration is missing at the server end, can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there's two ways to go about this. You can simply import `SparkGraphComputer` in the script that you're sending or you can add it to the `scriptEngines` configuration for your gremlin server. Something like

```
scriptEngines: {
  gremlin-groovy: {
    imports: [your.full.path.to.TheClass],
    staticImports: [your.full.path.to.TheClass.StaticVar]
   }
}
```

Comment: SparkGraphComputer is part of Tinkerpop Gremlin Server package itself and the jar containing its definition is also in its classpath, why would it be needed to specify the script specifically. It is able to resolve it in local mode, what goes wrong in remote mode.?

Comment: The jar containing the definition is in the classpath, you're right, otherwise importing the class wouldn't work. The gremlin server utilizes JSR223 to script on the jvm with Groovy, which means it's supplied a separate classloader. When the the JSR223 ScriptEngine calls `exec` to compile and run the script, the classes that you're using need to be loaded through the scripting engine classloader, necessitating the imports. Interactive (local) mode in TinkerPop loads several plugins which, I believe, do most of this class import stuff for you to make running examples easiser. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @pantalohnes, this is really helpful, I tried your suggestion and got past MissingPropertyException, but ended up into another exception -> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Graph does not support the provided graph computer: SparkGraphComputer, let me dig more into this and get back

Comment: Thanks @pantalohnes this was great help

Answer (score 0):

@pantalohnes answer works locally but doesn't work for remote connections, I've found.  At least in JanusGraph, I've had better luck adding the SparkGremlinPlugin to the list of plugins in the server yaml file:

```
scriptEngines:
  gremlin-groovy:
    plugins:
      org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.jsr223.SparkGremlinPlugin: {}
      org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.jsr223.GremlinServerGremlinPlugin: {}
    org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.jsr223.TinkerGraphGremlinPlugin: {}
```